# Making one to many to many Attribute Relationships

Tags: data, file-geodatabase, database, relationship-class

I am making relationship between three tables in QGIS 3.8 version (`"ACTIVE SITE"`,`"FUEL_TANK"`,`"REFUEL"`).
The primary key and the foreign key for the Tables are as follow

- the primary keys are `"ACTIVE SITE"`::`'SITE_NAME'`, `"FUEL_TANK"`::`'FUEL_TANK_ID'`, and `"REFUEL"`::`'REFUEL_ID'`
- the foreign keys are `"FUEL_TANK"`::`'SITE_NAME'` and `"REFUEL"`::`'FUEL_TANK_ID'`

I made the relationships as seen in the following image

[image]

in another word, I've linked the the `"ACTIVE SITE"` Table and `"FUEL_TANK"` Table with the foreign key `'SITE_NAME'`. And linked the the `"FUEL_TANK"` Table and `"REFUEL"` Table with the foreign key `'FUEL_TANK_ID'`.

the problem is when I add a new record in `"REFUEL"` Table the `'FUEL_TANK_ID'` takes the `'SITE_NAME'` from `"FUEL_TANK"` Table not the `'FUEL_TANK_ID'`

Am I doing something wrong??

And if I had a field in the `"REFUEL"` Table named `'SITE_NAME'` could it be filled automatically from the `'SITE_NAME'` field in the `"FUEL_TANK"` Table?? is there a way to do that??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the QGIS version from 3.8 to 3.4 and the relation between the tables worked perfectly. I assume that because version 3.8 is not stable yet!!